# Legend line symbol is not shown correctly in Seaborn plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting two line plots that represent a time series using seaborn and matplotlib, the issue is that the marker symbol is not shown in the legend in the output figure, instead a rectangle is shown.
NOTE: This code worked perfectly before so I don't know what the problem is.
The code is written below.

```
def plot_timeseries_for_certain_st(X_train, y_train, trans_pipe, y_trans, model, param, time_delta, 
                                   station,param_name_plot ='Chl-a'):
    
    X_train2 = trans_pipe.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test2 = trans_pipe.transform(X_test)  
    model.fit(X_train2, y_train)
    
    df_st = df[(df.time_delta <= time_delta) & (df.station.isin([station]))]
    
    y_st = df_st[param]
    X_st = df_st.drop([param], axis=1).drop(complement_cols, axis=1)
    
    X_st_trans = trans_pipe.transform(X_st)  
    param_st_preds = model.predict(X_st_trans)
    
    if y_trans is not None:
        rows = param_st_preds.shape[0]
        param_st_preds = y_trans.inverse_transform(param_st_preds.reshape(rows,1))

    
    df_st.insert(7,'param_preds', param_st_preds)
    dates = pd.to_datetime(df_st.Year*10000+df_st.Month*100+df_st.Day,format='%Y%m%d')
    df_st.insert(3,'Date', dates)
    df_st.sort_values(by='Date')
    
    plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
    sns.set_style("white")
    sns.set_context("talk")
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    bins= df_st.Date.unique()
    
    sns.lineplot(data=df_st, x='Date', y= param, marker='o')
    sns.lineplot(data=df_st, x='Date', y= 'param_preds', marker='^')
    
    
    
    title = param_name_plot+ ' time series at station '+str(station) +  ' (Actual vs. estimated)'
    plt.ylabel(param_name_plot)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid()
    
    plt.xticks(rotation=45);
    plt.legend(['Actual', 'Estimated'])
    
    if not os.path.exists('ProducedFigures/' + current_param):
        os.mkdir('ProducedFigures/' + current_param)
    plt.savefig('ProducedFigures/'+ current_param + '/' +title+'.png', dpi =1000, bbox_inches='tight') 
    
    
plot_timeseries_for_certain_st(X_train, y_train, trans_pipe, None, RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0), 
                               current_param, 10, 4, 'Temperature')
```

[image: The desired plot without the correct marker symbol]

Comment: The issue is not reproducible without a complete [mre], which should include sample data as formatted text.

Answer (score -1):

It should simply work if you provide `label` to the line plots by the following:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df_st, x='Date', y= param, marker='o', label = 'Actual')
sns.lineplot(data=df_st, x='Date', y= 'param_preds', marker='^', label = 'Estimated')
```

And then call the legend function:

```
plt.legend()
```

You don't need to send the handles manually as you did here: `plt.legend(['Actual', 'Estimated'])`. It would be automatically inferred from the labels.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, but sorry if I was not clear, this code worked perfectly before, so I don't know what the isuue is now.